# How to add dropdown menu to TextField?

Tags: flutter

I want to add a dropdown menu to TextField but I am confused. Here I attach my code and the design that I want to make.

```
SizedBox(
                width: 400,
                height: 64,
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Category Food',
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `DropdownButton` like this:

```
Container(
        decoration: ShapeDecoration(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            side: BorderSide(width: 1.0, style: BorderStyle.solid),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
          ),
        ),
        child: DropdownButton<String>(
          items: <String>[
            'Category 1',
            'Category 2',
            'Category 3',
            'Category 4'
          ].map((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value),
            );
          }).toList(),
          hint: Text(selectedCategory.isEmpty
              ? 'Category Food'
              : selectedCategory),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          underline: SizedBox(),
          isExpanded: true,
          onChanged: (value) {
            if (value != null) {
              setState(() {
                selectedCategory = value;
              });
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
```

and also define `selectedCategory` out of build method:

```
String selectedCategory = '';
```

[image]